# Hidden buttons Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am trying to test a hidden button in capybara but so far have not been able to get it to work without the following error.

```
undefined method `click_on' for [#<Capybara::Element tag="button">]
```

Could someone possibly suggest the correct syntax to do so.
The call is below:

```
When(/^I tap on the play button$/) do
    expect(page).to have_selector('.playback', visible: false)
    page.all('.playback').click_link
```

Comment: Are you trying to test that there is a visible `.playback` button? It does'nt really make much sense to test clicking a button which the user can't see, much less click.

Comment: I mentioned this on the current answer. But why would you want to try clicking on a hidden element? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your button is hidden, I think you need to do this:

`find(".playback", visible: false).click`

You can also try

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
find(".playback").click
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got the following error.  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)

Comment: @Emma the idea of these types of specs is to test the user journey. How would a user be clicking an invisible button?

Comment: Thanks I am afraid the issue might be deeper. I tried the above and also something similar in the env.rb file but i still get the above error.

Comment: That's because Selenium actually points the mouse at the element and tries to click it. I don't know the exact scenario but I think you should reconsider your approach

Comment: Because I am trying to test something now that wont always remain hidden.

Comment: This should _NOT_ be marked as an accepted answer for this question.  Users cannot click buttons that aren't visible.  If you want to test clicking a button that is not visible, make it visible first.

Comment: @tmg completely agree. Its fine to write a test for a future feature(TDD for example). But should you make it pass? No. Should you use this answer? No

Answer (score 0):

Ok so going from the comments/answers. Here is what I would do:

- Unhide the button.
- Make the spec pass. @tridadc 's answer should work.
- Mark the test as pending/TODO
- Put the button back to hidden.
- When the button is ready and visible, change the test from pending to active.